# How could I get the second line of grep's output as the input paramemeter to vim?

Tags: linux, shell

```
$ grep -l -R "myEditor_Init" *
Public/Js/eWebEditor/dialog/ewebeditor.htm
Public/Js/eWebEditor/ewebeditor.htm
Public/Js/eWebEditor/js/ewebeditor.js
```

For example, I would like to grep and vim the third file with one command, how could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes the third file more interesting than the other two?

Comment: becuase its the function 'myEditor_init' which I want to edit is in it.

Comment: Nothing in your grep command indicates that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ignacio implies, you can re-work your grep command to obtain *only* the one file you want, for instance:

```
$ grep -l -R --include="*.js" "myEditor_Init" *
Public/Js/eWebEditor/js/ewebeditor.js
```

In a case like this, you can edit it with, e.g. (use backticks to supply the result as an argument to vim:

```
$ vim `grep -l -R --include="*.js" "myEditor_Init" *`
```

If you really want to use * instead of limiting to *.js files, you could still do:

```
$ vim `grep -l -R "myEditor_Init" * | tail -1`
```

I often find myself (using csh or bash) doing something like the following:

```
$ grep -l -R --include="*.js" "myEditor_Init" *
Public/Js/eWebEditor/js/ewebeditor.js
$ vim `!!`
```

where `!!` repeats the previous command, and the backticks feed the result of that command as an argument to vim.

Comment: Just edited the suggested commands above, to allow for recursing in all local subdirectories.